# Web app and sales/marketing website in a single rails app, any advice on seperation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am familiar with rails engines, but was wondering for a more simple alternative.

A web application is the main rails 3 application in my project.
I have a simple sales/marketing website that has a main page, pricing page, about/contact, tour pages.  I could put most of these pages in 1 or 2 controllers.

I want to keep the css/js seperate, and was thinking of simply adding a folder inside the stylesheet and javascript folder.

Any other advice?

The 2 applications are linked in many ways, plus I don't want to manage/deploy 2 seperate websites seeing as the sales/marketing site is very simple and just contains some for the most part static pages.

Answer (score 2):

If they are truly static pages, you can just throw them in the public directory and be done. If you want them to utilize layouts etc, just go ahead and make a couple of controllers.

You can make a simple `PagesController` to deal with most of the static pages, and perhaps a separate controller to deal with the contact page submissions. In these controllers, just specify the other layout file that you want to use for the marketing pages.

For the css/js, if there are multiple files and you want to keep them separate from the rest of the app, then adding subdirs under each is not a bad way to go. If there is only one css and javascript file, I'd just name them different.